# Question about $C_c^{\infty}(]-1,1[)$ and Lipschitz spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

We denote by $D$ the space of the functions $C^{\infty}(]-1,1[)$ and compact support and $F$ the space of the Lipschitzian functions on $[-1,1]$.

For $f\in F$ and $\varphi\in D$, we note

$B(f,\varphi)=\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\varphi'(t)dt$

They ask me to show that:

1. Let $\varphi\in D$ be zero outside of $[-1 + \eta, 1 - \eta] $ (with $0 <\eta <1$). Show that for $\epsilon\in]0,\frac{\eta}{2}[$ we have

   $\int_{-1+\eta}^{1-\eta}\frac{f(t)-f(t+\epsilon)}{\epsilon}\varphi(t)dt=\int_{-1+\eta/2}^{1-\eta/2}f(t)\frac{\varphi(t)-\varphi(t-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}dt$
2. Prove that $|B(f,\varphi)|\le||f||_F||\varphi||_1$.

   Where, $||f||_F=\sup_{-1\le t\le 1}|f(t)|+\sup_{-1\le t\le
   1}|f'(t)|$

For the second item, I must use the first item.

But in the first item I intuit that I should use the derivative definition or that $f $ be in the Lipschitz function space.

Could you please help me?

Comment: What is $F$? $\ $

Comment: How have you defined the space $F$?

Comment: Presumably you have $\int f \phi' = \int f' \phi$ and so $|B(f,\phi)| \le \|f'\|_\infty \|\phi\|_1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch:** Note first that $\epsilon$ is a constant, so can be multiplied out from both integrals. Then, since $\phi(t)$ is zero outside $[1-\eta, 1-\eta]$, the $f(t) \phi(t)$ term can be ignored also. It then remains to show:

$$\int_{-1+\eta}^{1-\eta} f(t+\epsilon) \phi(t) \, dt = \int_{-1+\frac{\eta}{2}}^{1-\frac{\eta}{2}} f(t) \phi(t-\epsilon) \, dt.$$

Perform a substitution on the right hand side, then consider the intervals that both integrals are defined over, and use the range of $\epsilon$ to conclude.